# Functions and random numbers

Tags: python

Write a program that displays a table of ten distance equivalents in miles and kilometers. See Example output. You must generate the table by running a function inside a loop in main. Generate a random integer from 10 to 60, inclusive, in each loop cycle. Use this latter value as the miles argument to the function. The function must then print a line in the table. Repeat: The function prints the table.  Print  the miles in a column 5 characters wide with 2 decimals and the kilometers in a column 13 characters wide with 5 decimals.

Example output

```
MILES   KILOMETERS
52.00     83.68568
11.00     17.70274
40.00     64.37360
21.00     33.79614
14.00     22.53076
23.00     37.01482
48.00     77.24832
22.00     35.40548
15.00     24.14010
16.00     25.74944
```

this is how far I have gotten. Any help from anyone about this problem will be greatly appreciated.I am completely new to python and coding aswell.

```
import random

def result(km,miles):

    CONVERSION_FACTOR = 1.61
    km = random.randrange(10,25) * CONVERSION_FACTOR
    miles = km/CONVERSION_FACTOR

    print(format(km,'13.5f'),'\t',format(miles,'5.2f'),sep='')


def main():
print ('--------------')
for num in range (10):
    result(10,50)##Want to pass these values into the
                 ##random.randrange function if possible
    


main()
```

Comment: Please rephrase your quesiton to clearly indicate what you've done so far and what you have left, as well as what specifically you're stuck on. Just dumping your code and the problem statement, then expecting us to finish it for you with no effort on your part, isn't cool.

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment for a course. Having someone on Stackoverflow may not be the best way to complete the assignment.

Comment: @RandomDavis so far I have been able to generate the random numbers and do the conversions. But I want to be able to pass a range of (10,60) or any range into the random.randrange function in the main function to do the calculations. Right now the only way I can make this program to do any calculations is by changing the range that is already in the random.randrange function.

Comment: @aamir23 Yes it is a homework assignment that I need help with. I know it's not the best way or the ideal way to complete this assignment. but right now this way is the only way I have now.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Why does result() take km as an argument and then just re-assign the value before it's ever used?
2. According to the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#316-naming), only global constants should be capitalized.
3. From the excerpt you posted it seems to me that they want a function which takes a randomly generated miles value as a argument and converts that to Km. Your's currently converts Km to miles.

Either way you can just pass `random.randrange()` into the function call like so:

```
result(50,random.randrange(10,50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would pass the values to random.randrange() from main()

```
import random

def result(range1,range2):

    CONVERSION_FACTOR = 1.61
    km = random.randrange(range1,range2) * CONVERSION_FACTOR
    miles = km/CONVERSION_FACTOR
    print(format(km,'13.5f'),'\t',format(miles,'5.2f'),sep='')


def main():
    print ('--------------')
    for num in range (10):
        result(10,60)
    
main()
```

Based on the problem statement you posted, it seems like the result function should only have one argument i.e miles and not two like the code sample you posted.

I just re-arranged your code to closely match what the problem statement is asking. Instead of generating the random number in the result() function I am generating it in the main function and passing the random value as input argument for the result() function.

```
import random

def result(miles):
    CONVERSION_FACTOR = 1.61
    km = miles * CONVERSION_FACTOR
    print(format(miles,'5.2f'),'\t',format(km,'13.5f'),sep='')

def main():
    print ('MILES \t KILOMETERS')
    for num in range (10):
        result(random.randrange(10,25))

main()
```